# ruby openssl hmac php equivalent

Tags: php, ruby, openssl, sha1, hmac

I have to convert this ruby code into PHP equivalent.

```
[OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), secret_key, policy)].pack("m").strip
```

I converted it into the following code but I'm not sure if it is correct or not.

```
$s = hash_hmac('sha1', $secret_key, $policy);
$s = base64_encode($sig);
$s = trim($sig);
return $s;
```

I'm not sure if I need to set the last parameter of hash_hmac to true:

```
$sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $secret_key, $policy, true);
```

or none is correct and should do this in a different way.

Which would be the correct equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I have just installed ruby myself to test. I have tested and the equivalent is:

```
$sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $policy, $secret_key, true);
$sig = base64_encode($sig);
$sig = trim($sig);
return $sig;
```

The order of parameters is inverted in php, first data, then key. And the raw_output parameter needs to be true.